# variable declaration not allowed here

Tags: variables, foreach, hashmap, declaration, hashset

```
 private HashMap<String, String> answers;

 public String generateResponse(HashSet<String> word)
 {
    for(String word : words)
     String answer = answers.get(word);
    if(answer != null){
        return answer;
    }else {
        return standardAnswers();
    }
 }
```

I have imported HashMap. And I want for every word in HashSet to get it in HashMap<> answers. But in the for-each loop says:   variable declaration not allowed here

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A declaration is not a statement, so it's not allowed in that spot.

If it were, `answer` would be out of scope at the if statement anyways.

Use a block scope to declare and use `answer`:

```
 private HashMap<String, String> answers;

 public String generateResponse(HashSet<String> word)
 {
    for(String word : words)
    {
        String answer = answers.get(word);
        if(answer != null){
            return answer;
        } else {
            return standardAnswers();
        }
    }
 }
```